# Match Dates and Count in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables:

```
create table dbo.Dates (
  Id int not null
    constraint Dates_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id),
  [DateValue] date not null
}

create table dbo.Posts (
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint Posts_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id),
  Created datetime not null,
  Title nvarchar (200) not null
)
```

For these tables I have Date and Post entities.

How can I get a table that has the column DateValue from Dates and the number of Posts with that date.

I need to match the datetime Created value to the date DateValue.

Thank you,

Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `Post`s have dates with times, so you'll have to truncate them to the date part (as in the `Date` property of a `DateTime`):

```
from d in context.Dates
select new { 
             Date = d.DateValue,
             NrOfPosts = (from p in context.Posts
                 where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Created) == d.DateValue
                 select p).Count()
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use anonymous types. try the following snippet.

```
DateTime dateToMatch = GetDateToMatch();

using(YourEntities context = new YourEntities())
{
    var result = context.Dates.Where(d => d.DateValue == dateToMatch)
                              .Select(d => new { Date = d.DateValue, PostCount = d.Posts.Count() });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong. I am looking for have a new tables with all Dates.DateValue and Posts.Cound ... Not a specific one.